# WPF fails to resize a controle

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0

I've already scoured my XAML file for the word "Width" and it only appears with a number as a value at the root element, setting the width of the entire control. The word "height" only has a numerical value at the root element and two textboxes that aren't in the same Grid cell as the checkbox below.

Unfortunately, regardless of the values I set in the UserControl element for height and width, the following checkbox doesn't get bigger:

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                        <Grid ToolTipService.ToolTip="">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="path" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Image x:Name="lightbulb" Source="BestLogin_Images/lightbulb.png" ToolTipService.ToolTip=""/>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Margin="140,0,0,0" Content="" ToolTipService.ToolTip=""/>
                            <Path x:Name="path" Data="M41.75,5.5 L53.75,2.25 L58.5,0.75 L65.75,1.5 L73,3.75 L83.25,8.25 L88.5,13.25 L95.5,21 L102,33.75 L102.5,44.5 L97.5,59.25 L90.25,74.75 L86.5,82.5 L84.25,91.5 L83.75,96.5 L79.5,104.25 L79.75,108.75 L78.5,113.25 L80,114.5 L79.75,119.75 L79,126 L76.75,132 L74.5,134.5 L68.75,140.5 L65,142 L64.53125,143.125 L62.75,144.75 L61.4375,145.59375 L57.71875,145.90601 L55.15625,143.46875 L53.4375,142.40625 L50.625,141.46875 L47.15625,137.34375 L43.5,135 L40.375,129.84375 L39.5,128.53125 L40.4375,127.375 L41.25,126.09375 L41.15625,124.78125 L39.15625,123.65625 L39.343998,121.5625 L39.343998,116.15625 L39.406498,111.3125 L38.750252,104.90625 L35.583599,99.791664 L35.292271,91.125 L33.375278,80.75 L31.54195,77.583336 L26.791613,69.75 L21.332918,59.541668 L19.874918,56.25 L19.08325,37.708332 L19.37525,36.75 L21.750242,27.333334 L27.041893,18.416666 L31.79188,11.833333 L37.416862,7.0833335 L38.791859,6.5833335 z" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19.083,0.75,0,18.094" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#B2FFF500" Opacity="0" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Click me to light up your day."/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
...snip...(Grid layout)    
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle1}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" Name="CheckBox1" />
```

Comment: Well, honestly, I don't see why it should get bigger.

Comment: Me neither but try putting it in a ViewBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sizes of elements in WPF are determined by more than just Width and Height. You also need to consider all of the Alignment settings: HorizontalAlignment, VerticalAlignment, and sometimes HorizontalContentAlignment, and VerticalContentAlignment, as well as the layout Panels being used to arrange your elements. Here you've left-aligned the CheckBox so it will never get a bigger Width than the minimum it needs. You haven't included the Grid XAML but I suspect that the Row for the CheckBox may be set to Height="Auto" but I can't tell for sure without seeing the rest of the layout.

Comment: For people stumbling across this thread later, there are 2 parts involved:
1. Read up on how horizontal/vertical alignment work in your layout.
2. Go through and make sure things that should grow to fill use the asterisk (*) units instead of just numbers.